# Gait analysis for multiple people

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make changes to a project that was passed down to me about human gait analysis. The issue im running into now is that while the results of the gait analysis works fine on multiple people. Im not able to display the correct results to the correct person, instead it only displays the latest result of one person for both people.

Below is the code which displays the texts on the webcam video. it uses the nose coordinates of each person as the coordinate to display each person's gait.

```
import cv2, numpy

print(results) 

for _, item in enumerate(nose_coordinates):
    #  print(f'Person {_+1}: item {item} ')
    person_text = f"Person {_+1}: {results[_][0]}"
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    if text == 'Steady':
        color = (0, 255, 0)
    elif text == 'Unsteady':
        color = (0, 0, 255)
    else:
        color = (0, 255, 255)
    cv2.putText(frame, person_text, (item[0], item[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
```

When I run it in anaconda the `print(results)` will show the resuts correctly for each person detected.

e.g. if person 1 is steady, person is unsteady, it will print `[["steady"],["unsteady"]]`.

But the displayed text in the window will be

```
person 1:steady
person 2:steady
```

or

```
person 1:unsteady
person 2:unsteady
```

I have considered trying multithreading to create a new thread for each person's results but that does not work for my project since I need it to analyse all people in the camera view. im using the laptop webcam to test for now.

I also tried using output layers:

```
def get_output_layers(net):
    layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    return output_layers
```

but this also still gave only the latest result.

Below is the entire code for analysing the gait from the keypoints drawn:

```
ret, frame = camera.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        try:
            # Check for the 'esc' key to exit
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                break

            output, frame = run_inference(frame)
            frame, distances, output, keypoints_list = draw_keypoints(output, frame)

            # Calculate FPS
            frame_count += 1
            elapsed_time = (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
            fps = frame_count / elapsed_time

            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            # Put FPS text on the frame
            cv2.putText(frame, f"FPS: {fps:.2f}", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            # Initialize lists to store results for each person
            # results_per_person = [[] for _ in range(len(keypoints_list))]

            for idx, keypoints in enumerate(keypoints_list):
                
                p_count = keypoints['total_person']
                
                if len(arr) <= idx:
                    arr.append([])
                    # print(f'Person {idx+1}:  {arr[idx]} in {arr}')
                elif len(arr) > p_count:
                    arr.pop()
                    # print(f'Person {idx+1}: Updated {arr[idx]} in {arr}')

                # Get Nose coordinates
                Nose_x = keypoints['keypoints'][0]
                Nose_y = keypoints['keypoints'][1]

                Nose_x = int(Nose_x)
                Nose_y = int(Nose_y)
                    
                LS_y = keypoints['keypoints'][16]
                RS_y = keypoints['keypoints'][19]
                LHip_x = keypoints['keypoints'][33]
                LHip_y = keypoints['keypoints'][34]
                RHip_x = keypoints['keypoints'][36]
                RHip_y = keypoints['keypoints'][37]
                LA_x = keypoints['keypoints'][45]
                LA_y = keypoints['keypoints'][46]
                RA_x = keypoints['keypoints'][48]
                RA_y = keypoints['keypoints'][49]
                LA_conf = keypoints['keypoints'][47]
                RA_conf = keypoints['keypoints'][50]

                Hip_x = ((LHip_x - RHip_x) / 2) + RHip_x
                Hip_y = (LHip_y + RHip_y) / 2
                shoulder_y = (LS_y + RS_y) / 2
                d = abs(Hip_y - shoulder_y)

                if len(arr[idx]) < counting:
                    
                    if LA_conf > 0.8 and RA_conf > 0.8:
                        if text != "Default":
                            text = text

                        if d == 0.0:
                            LAx = 15
                            LAy = 90
                            RAx = 15
                            RAy = 90
                        else:
                            LA_x = round(abs((LA_x - Hip_x) / d) * 100, 2)
                            LA_y = round(abs((LA_y - Hip_y) / d) * 100, 2)
                            RA_x = round(abs((RA_x - Hip_x) / d) * 100, 2)
                            RA_y = round(abs((RA_y - Hip_y) / d) * 100, 2)

                            if LA_x == 0.0:
                                LAx = LAx
                            elif LA_x < 5.0:
                                LAx = 15
                            else:
                                LAx = LA_x

                            if LA_y == 0.0:
                                LAy = LAy
                            elif LA_y < 70.0:
                                LAy=90
                            else:
                                LAy = LA_y

                            if RA_x == 0.0:
                                RAx = RAx
                            elif RA_x < 5.0:
                                RAx=15
                            else:
                                RAx = RA_x

                            if RA_y == 0.0:
                                RAy = RAy
                            elif RA_y < 70.0:
                                RAy = 90
                            else:
                                RAy=RA_y
                        
                        keypoints_sequence = [LAx,LAy,RAx,RAy]
                        # print(f'Person {idx+1} Keypoints Data|| {arr[idx]}')
                        arr[idx].append(keypoints_sequence)

                        x = x + 1

                    else:
                        
                        check += 1
                        if check == 48:
                            # print(f'\n No Foot detected|| Left Ankle: {str(keypoints[47])} + Right Ankle: {str(keypoints[50])}')
                            check = 0
                            text = "No Foot Detected"

                elif len(arr[idx]) == counting:
                    # print(f'Person {idx+1} Keypoints Data|| {arr[idx]}')
                    
                    # Extract individual keypoint coordinates
                    keypoints_data = np.array(arr[idx])  # Convert the list of lists to a NumPy array
                    LAx_data = keypoints_data[:, 0]  # Extract LAx values
                    RAx_data = keypoints_data[:, 2]  # Extract RAx values
                    # print(f' LAx: {LAx_data} |||\n RAx: {RAx_data}')

                    # Calculate standard deviations
                    STDKP_R = statistics.stdev(RAx_data)
                    STDKP_L = statistics.stdev(LAx_data)
                    # print(f' STD_R: {STDKP_R}\n STD_L: {STDKP_L}')

                    if (STDKP_R > 3.6) or (STDKP_L > 3.6):
                        
                        # Extract individual keypoint coordinates
                        keypoints_data = np.array(arr[idx])  # Convert the list of lists to a NumPy array                        
                        keypoints_data = keypoints_data.reshape(-1, sequence_length, feature_dims)
                        # print(f' Input Data Shape: {keypoints_data}')
                        print(f'Person {idx+1} Input Data Shape: {keypoints_data.shape}')
                        predictions = model.predict(keypoints_data)  # Assuming X is your input data
                        print(f'Prediction: {predictions}')
                        predicted = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
                        # print(f'Predicted: {predicted}')
                        if 0 in predicted:
                            text = 'Steady'
                        else:
                            text = 'Unsteady'
                    else:
                        text = 'No Movement Detected'

                    arr[idx].clear()
                    x = 0

                #  # Append classification result to the corresponding results list
                # results_per_person[idx].append(text)
                # append to results list 
                nose_coordinates.append([Nose_x-230, Nose_y])
                results.append([text])
                #print(f'Person {idx+1}: {results}')

            print(results)
            for _, item in enumerate(nose_coordinates):
                # print(f'Person {_+1}: item {item} ')
                person_text = f"Person {_+1}: {results[_][0]}"
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
                if text == 'Steady':
                    color = (0, 255, 0)
                elif text == 'Unsteady':
                    color = (0, 0, 255)
                else:
                    color = (0, 255, 255)
                cv2.putText(frame, person_text, (item[0], item[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

            # for idx, result_list in enumerate(results_per_person):
            #     for j, result in enumerate(result_list):
            #         person_text = f"Person {idx+1}: {result}"
            #         frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            #         if result == 'Steady':
            #             color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green color for steady
            #         elif result == 'Unsteady':
            #             color = (0, 0, 255)  # Red color for unsteady
            #         else:
            #             color = (0, 255, 255)  # Yellow color for no movement detected
            #         nose_x, nose_y = nose_coordinates[idx]
            #         frame = cv2.putText(frame, person_text, (nose_x, nose_y + (30 * (j + 1))),
            #                             cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            #         frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            #         results_per_person[idx].append(result)

            cv2.imshow('Yolov7 Pose', cv2.flip(frame, 1))

            nose_coordinates, results = [], []

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    # Release the camera
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you want to use the index returned by `enumerate`, don't assign it to `_`, it typically indicates that you want to ignore a value. I don't know if this is causing your issue.

Comment: ohh so do i just use
for item in enumerate(nose_coordinates): ?

Comment: No, you need the index e.g. to create the "person #" string. But use `for i, item in enumerate(...)` and then `f"Person {i+1}: {results[i][0]}"`.

Comment: alright i have tried to assign it to i instead of _.  The output on the video is still the assigning the same results to both and this time it is only able to display the first letter of each result

Comment: Then you have changed something else as well.

Comment: hmm i only chaned the _ tho
            for i, item in enumerate(nose_coordinates):
                # print(f'Person {_+1}: item {item} ')
                person_text = f"Person {i+1}: {results[i][0]}"
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
                if text == 'Steady':
                    color = (0, 255, 0)
                elif text == 'Unsteady':
                    color = (0, 0, 255)
                else:
                    color = (0, 255, 255)